# Java lib for visualizing large social networks

Tags: java, networking, visualization

Is there any lib for visualizing large social networks? Moreover, does it make sense to visualize them at all if a network has e.g. 200 000 edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is probably the best tool for this; it comes with [Java bindings](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gv.3java.pdf) and deals well with large graphs. It's pretty complex, but also very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

You can google java social network visualization.

Some stuff I found:
http://jung.sourceforge.net/

http://www.isi.edu/~blythe/KP/

Do some research and you may find more.

Answer (score 1):

I once used [gephi](http://gephi.org/) for graphs visualization. They have some modules for social network analysis too.